# BJT voltage rail

Tags: power-supply, batteries, pcb, circuit-design, bjt

I have run into some misunderstandings regarding voltage rails in circuits with components such as BJTs. And not the BJTs, but rather the conventional current model schematic made, and the **real thing**, that is done in an actual circuit.

[image]

*A degenerate amplifier with -1 gain*

The schematic is how a circuit looks on paper, with current flowing from positive to ground, or negative, and with current flowing from the collector to the emitter as the arrow suggests. In a real circuit it goes the opposite way.  In the Art Of Electronicd, 3rd edition it is said that the transistor is functioning in reverse bias mode. But this is the conventional current model. In an actual circuit their would be no current flowing in the reverse bias direction, right?

[image]

This is how I imagine that it would work in a real circuit. The current flows normally from emitter to collector in an npn, and from negative (ground in this case) to positive. Does it work like this or it the first image really how a bjt circuit works? Except for current flowing from emitter to collector, is the circuit really reverse biased in a real circuit? Or is this only the conventional current model at work for this schematic? Positive terminal I would regard the +5V rail and the negative side the ground. How is a real circuit working compared to its design in a circuit schematic? Is the +5v rail actually the positive polarisation of that wire because of the carrieer hole of the positive terminal of the battery... or not? I am now reffering to a general case, for all bjt circuits, not just the one above. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Why are you talking about current direction? When the base voltage of an NPN transistor is positive by about 0.7V and the collector or its load has a positive voltage then the collector to emitter conducts current.

Comment: @Audioguru because current direction is determined by the voltage at the terminals, and reverse bias means both that the polarisation of a component is reversed, or that the current flows in the "wrong" direction. I couldn't after all say that "voltage flows" thru the transistor. It is easier to say it this way.

Comment: @Audioguru and also I did say that in the conventional model current flows opposite from the real thing. I don't want the conventional current model because that is the one that got me stuck in the first place. On one hand the art of electronics saying that reverse bias is the normal transistor operation, and on the other hand the knowledge that I have about how current actually flows thru such a circuit. It got me a bit stuck in some aspects as you saw in my question. This is why I am asking how does it actually work in a real circuit so that I know how current flows and where.

Comment: @Audioguru I only wonder because it is noted as +5V on the rail connected to the positive terminal of a battery, and the rail connected to the negative terminal is shown as 0 volts (in simulations as well). Which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: For over 60 years I know that the base-emitter of a bipolar transistor is forward-biased to turn it on and that the collector of an NPN always has a positive voltage and a PNP collector has a negative voltage. The only "reverse-bias" in a transistor that is important is when the base-emitter voltage causes avalanche breakdown. I never ever think about current direction or electrons or holes.

Comment: The voltage polarity determines whether the BJT is forward or reverse-biased. Not the current direction flow.

Comment: I think you need to more clearly differentiate between when you're talking about "conventional current" flow and "charge carrier (aka electron)" flow. No matter whether you're considering a schematic on paper or a real circuit with real components, "conventional current" always flows from positive to negative. "Charge carrier" flow could be in either direction, depending on what the carriers are, for example negatively charged electrons in a wire or positively charged ions in a solution. For most normal circuit analysis, "charge carrier" flow is rarely useful and often confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In electronics we use conventional current flow, current flows from positive to negative. If you try to learn it using electron flow you're going to be swimming against the current (pun intended) as all of the textbooks and literature are going to use conventional flow.

A PN junction is considered forward biased when the P type material is at a more positive voltage than the N type material. An NPN transistor will normally be biased with the base more positive than the emitter and the collector more positive than the base. This makes the BE junction forward biased and the BC junction reverse biased. Base current then flows from the base to the emitter and collector current flows from the collector to the emitter.

Comment: I tried to avoid conventional current, but as a more thorough search took place I discovered that theoretically both models are correct. In analyzing circuits tho it seems that conventional current is indeed more suitable. I will perhaps try to combine both. It looks like it both opposing models make use of the relative motion of charge carriers with respect to a reference point. And as +Voltage "moves" carriers to the negative terminals it resembles the movement of a gas at a higher pressure to a lower one. Or it might be seen as the net increase in entropy of the system.-

Comment: Thus electrons being negative they move to the more positive terminal, decreasing it's potential and instead increasing that of the negative terminal (just like a gas achieving equilibrum). I can also think of it, as I said, perhaps in terms of a relative reference point. I think that not exploring the conventional model as well, I blinded myself from the actual mechanics of a circuit. Thanks for posting because it got me thinking and searching. And sorry for the long talk,  but I generally like to leave such posts as for myself, commenting at posts that did help me understand better. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidAb Don't try to use both unless you're concerned with movement of carriers inside a semiconductor, or plasma physics. It just gets confusing. Just use conventional current flow.

Comment: @DavidAb Unless you really want to get into the theory of how semiconductors work at the atomic level you're overthinking it. For circuit design and analysis you don't really need to know what the electrons and holes are doing. As long as you're current directions are consistent and you don't mix conventional with electron flow it works out.

Comment: @DavidAb There is a place and time where the actual particles matter (quantum, plasma, and solid state physics.) But if you aren't thinking at the level of microelectronics and semi-conductors (or other esoteric situations that may arise in rare circumstances from time to time, such as differential heating at cathodes and anodes in plasma gas physics for example), emergent phenomena allow you to ignore such details. Ben Franklin is credited with the flip of the coin choice of where we are at with "conventional current." It was a random historical result and we live with it, now.